# Breed-on Patch-Set Code not working properly

Tags: netlogo

The code for the procedure to-recruit has worked well for many iterations of the model, but recently the first turtle seems to bounce off the food and change color to orange, likely as part of the look-for food procedure, instead of changing breed and turning white. If the turtle goes onto/into the area of the food-patches, it seems to work smoothly, but they seem to be contacting the edges of the food-patch, and somehow triggering the look-for-food procedure. Alternatively, the breed transformation (ask leaders ... set breed foragers, set color orange + 1) in the abbreviated to go code may be occurring, but that seems less likely. I tried expanding the patch-set to include the edge patches that seem to be triggering this change, but this did not work. Any help resolving this problem would be appreciated.

````````
to go
   ask foragers
    [wiggle
     fd 1
     look-for-food
     recruit
     reemerge]
ask leaders
  [wiggle
    fd 1
    return-to-nest
    if count followers with [color = violet] >= 2  ;; transform leader into forager that has found food
    [set breed foragers
     set color orange + 1]]
tick
end

to look-for-food  ;; forager procedure
  if food > 0
  [ set color orange + 1     ;; change color to indicate that they have picked up food
    set food food - 1        ;; and reduce the food source
   facexy nest-x nest-y
    uphill-nest-scent
    fd 1]
  ask foragers with [color = yellow]
  [if not any? followers and food-quality <= 0.6
    [let choice random 3
    (ifelse
        choice = 0
   [uphill-false-food-scent-a]
      choice = 1
      [uphill-food]
       ;;;;;;;;
        [uphill-chemical])]]
  if food-quality > 0.6 and color = yellow
  [uphill-chemical
    fd 3]
end

to recruit  ;; forager procedure
  let potential-leaders foragers-on (patch-set patch -37 -17 patch -36 -17 patch -35 -17 patch -38 -18 patch -37 -18 patch -36 -18 patch -35 -18 patch -34 -18 patch -39 -19 patch -38 -19 patch -37 -19 patch -36 -19 patch -35 -19 patch -34 -19 patch -33 -19 patch -39 -20 patch -38 -20 patch -37 -20 patch -36 -20 patch -35 -20 patch -34 -20 patch -33 -20 patch -39 -21 patch -38 -21 patch -37 -21 patch -36 -21 patch -35 -21 patch -34 -21 patch -33 -21 patch -38 -22 patch -37 -22 patch -36 -22 patch -35 -22 patch -34 -22 patch -37 -23 patch -36 -23 patch -35 -23)
  if any? potential-leaders and not any? leaders and food > 0 and count foragers <= 10  ;; checks if any leaders exist
  [ ask one-of potential-leaders
    [ set breed leaders
    set color white]]  ;; transforms first forager to find food into the leader
end
```````
````````

Comment: Since the look-for-food procedure is the one that is being triggered wrongly (turning to orange), then it's likely that the cause is the procedure that requests the look-for-food procedure. As far as I can see, you have not provided that code.

Comment: Just edited to add that code!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the problem is that you have the turtles moving in two different procedures, both of which are called within the same tick. Imagine forager A who does this (cut down version of your code):

```
to go
  ask foragers
  [ wiggle
    forward 1        ; moves 1
    look-for-food
    ...
  ]
  tick
end
```

So A moves forward in a semi-random direction and then calls the look-for-food procedure. Imagine further that there is food at their patch:

```
to look-for-food
  if food > 0
  [ set color orange + 1
    set food food - 1
    facexy nest-x nest-y
    uphill-nest-scent
    forward 1                ; moves again if found food
  ]
  ...
  if food-quality > 0.6 and color = yellow
  [ uphill-chemical
    forward 3                ; potentially moves again
  ]
end
```

So forager A passes the condition at the top, changes colour and then moves toward its nest. Furthermore, if other conditions are met, it moves another 3 distance.